# Execute shell command doesn't work in Android 7

Tags: java, android, process

I need to execute some shell commands in app. This code works fine in Android 5, but not in Android 7. Debug output: `process: Process[pid=13559, hasExited=true, exitcode=1]`. Error stream: `Permission denied`. How can I make it work in all android versions? Is there any change in Android between versions 5 to 7 that disables running shell commands? Code:

```
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -l");

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

    char[] buffer = new char[5000];
    int numRead;
    while ((numRead = bufferedReader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        commandOutput.append(buffer, 0, numRead);
    }

    bufferedReader.close();
    process.waitFor();
}
catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return commandOutput.toString();
```

Comment: Exit codes other than 0 mean there's been a problem. Read it from the error stream.

Comment: Did you try to read the error stream?

Comment: Thanks, error stream result: Permission denied. Still no idea how to fix it